# How can I detect a debugger or other tool that might be analysing my software?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2007, testing

A very simple situation. I'm working on an application in Delphi 2007 which is often compiled as 'Release' but still runs under a debugger. And occasionally it will run under SilkTest too, for regression testing. While this is quite fun I want to do something special...

I want to detect if my application is running within a debugger/regression-tester and if that's the case, I want the application to know which tool is used! (Thus, when the application crashes, I could report this information in it's error report.)

Any suggestions, solutions?

Comment: You aren't writing malware, right...?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/using-an-exception-handler

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the parent process that started your application.
With `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`/`Process32First`/`Process32Next` get the parent PID (`PROCESSENTRY32.th32ParentProcessID` or `TProcessEntry32.th32ParentProcessID`) for your application PID. Then get the filename for the parent PID to compare with the applications you want to check for, like SilkTest.

Check [this article](http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/windows/get_exe_path_from_window_handle.html) for code usage.

In addition to `IsDebuggerPresent` and `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent`, you can also query `PEB.BeingDebugged` (PEB is Process Environment Block, to get PEB you must query TEB, which is the Thread Enviroment Block).

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for the [`IsDebuggerPresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345(VS.85).aspx) function.

Comment: But will it also detect SilkTest and other testing software? Or remote debuggers?

Comment: There is also the `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent` function, which sounds like it might identify remote debuggers. I'm unfamiliar with SilkTest so I don't know whether it acts as a debugger or not. If it does, then the above will work. If not, then you will need to find another technique.

Answer (score 1):

To detect SilkTest, you could try to attach to a DLL which is used only by SilkTest in order to detect its presence. For example, if the Open Agent is attached to a process, `Win32HookDll_x86.dll` or `Win32HookDll_amd64.dll` will be present (the names can be easily found out with a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).

Answer (score -1):

You can also do

```
if DebugHook <> 0 then ...
```

Comment: That only works from within the Delphi IDE, not other debuggers. Also, keep in mind the application is debugged in "Release" mode, not "Debug" mode.