# How to detect a debugger is running on MacOS with Delphi

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Is there a way to detect a debugger is running with Delphi on MacOS?

For example:

```
System.DebugHook <> 0
```

or call somehow the [c function](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1361/_index.html)

```
AmIBeingDebugged()
```

from Pascal code

Comment: Apparently AmIBeingDebugged is not sufficient. I attempted to use this function, converting it into Delphi: https://gist.github.com/zorgiepoo/10555752 however it returns True regardless of whether or not the app is being run through the debugger

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443268/how-can-i-detect-a-debugger-or-other-tool-that-might-be-analysing-my-software

Comment: I don't know anything about Delphi, but it is just a system call if you can perform those from Delphi. If you can perform a shell command you can also offload this to an external binary.

Comment: maybe this is how you can make a systemcall from Delphi: https://theroadtodelphi.com/tag/sysctl/ somebody that knows Delphi can probably turn that into an answer for you by looking at the syscall made from `AmIBeingDebugged()`.